# Cocoapods ld: framework not found KIF - ONLY when testing on a real device

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, kif, kif-framework

As the title says I get the following error:

> Showing Recent Messages
>   ld: framework not found KIF
>
> error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/[User]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[App].app/PlugIns/[AppTests].xctest/[AppTests]": No such file or directory

Strangely enough the above happens only on a real device and only when I test the app.

I use swift 3 & Xcode 8, and this is my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'App' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
  pod 'KeychainAccess'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 6.0'
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'KIF'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.0.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
  end

  target 'AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.0.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have seen this as well. The workaround to this is to manually `rsync` necessary files to the .app folder.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @Jargen89 example: `rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/KIF/KIF.framework"  "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/OCMock/OCMock.framework" `